# Firebase function to return document result inside swift func

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a function to get a specific document from the Firebase Firestore. This is my code:

```
func getDocumentFromFirebase(collection: String, documentId: String) -> [String: String] {

    var firebaseResult = [String: String]()
    let docRef = db.collection(collection).document(documentId)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            var property = document.get("name") as! String
            //print("Document data string: \(property)")
            firebaseResult["name"] = property

            return firebaseResult
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I would like to return the result in a Dictionary, but I get an error on my return line:

> "Unexpected non-void return value in void function."

But when I move it a few lines down, returns before the Firebase call is completed and the Dictionary is empty.

I understand that I am trying to return the result in a Dictionary, inside a Void function to get the document from Firebase.

My question is, how do I return the result of the Firebase call in the Dictionary after the document is retrieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a completion as you can't return a value inside fireStore closure

```
func getDocumentFromFirebase(collection: String, documentId: String,completion:@escaping(([String: String]?) -> ()))   { 
    var firebaseResult = [String: String]()
    let docRef = db.collection(collection).document(documentId) 
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            var property = document.get("name") as! String
            //print("Document data string: \(property)")
            firebaseResult["name"] = property 
            completion(firebaseResult)
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

call

```
getDocumentFromFirebase(_,_) { res in 

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks the above was very helpful - if your completion was just a String, once you return it is it possible to store it as a variabe? Or can you only print it within the { } of the call?

Answer (score 0):

the function calling the getDocumentFromFirebase would have access to the what's passed in the completion(....)

the "res" as the above answer details is what was passed into the completion as a parameter which would be the result from firebase this is an example I have implemented

```
func getUser(userId: String, completion: @escaping((_ user: User?) -> ())) {
    let docRef = db.collection(Collection.users.rawValue).document(userId)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let returnedUser = try? document.data(as: User.self)
            completion(returnedUser)
        } else {
            print("user doesn't exist")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```